# What is the result of an Oracle query with COUNT and no parameters

Tags: oracle

I'm comfortable with SQL Server, but not so much with Oracle.

I've got a query that looks something like the following:

```
SELECT umr.region, payee_name, COUNT, corporate_office_name
FROM payers, offices, 
( 
  SELECT region, h.payee_name, COUNT, company_name FROM someTable h, someTable2
  GROUP BY region, h.payee_name, company_name
) umr
WHERE ...
```

I know that the example isn't complete, but the key to the question is what is the `COUNT` in the `SELECT` statement telling Oracle to do?

Comment: nothing it will generate a syntax error without identifying a field or * to count.  unless there's a count column in sometable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it means there's a column called `count` in one of the tables.

Comment: Yep! I was sure I didn't understand Oracle SQL, but after looking more closely, I saw a COUNT(something) COUNT, in one of the sub selects.  What threw me was that the COUNT column name was on a separate line.   Grr!

Comment: I couldn't have said it better myself.  Nothing like inheriting code and trying to understand it when stupid things are done...

Comment: Regardless of it being a reserved word, it's a bad choice for a column name anyway as there's no context to it. Obviously it is the number of something, but of what?